# set cookie Local in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want set cookie to the browser but that is don't save.

My function:

```
function setValue(p_lang) {

    document.cookie = "lg="+p_lang+";expires=Fri, 17 Dec 2020 10:00:00 GMT";

    if (p_lang == "en") {
        document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = MenuEng[0];
        document.getElementById("about").innerHTML = MenuEng[1];
        document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML = MenuEng[2];
    }
    if (p_lang == "az") {
        document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = MenuAze[0];
        document.getElementById("about").innerHTML = MenuAze[1];
        document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML = MenuAze[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an expiry date (in UTC time). By default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

With a path parameter, you can tell the browser what path the cookie belongs to. By default, the cookie belongs to the current page.

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```